# changing the values in connection string gives NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

When I change the values of username, password and url in Connection string in web.config I get null reference exception.It is working for environment but when I change those value I get error.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CRM" connectionString="AuthType=Office365;Url=url; Username=""; Password="" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Here is the connection code:

```
public class get
{
    private CrmServiceClient crmSvc = null;
    private IOrganizationService crmService = null;

    public get()
    {
        this.crmSvc = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM"].ConnectionString);
        this.crmService = this.crmSvc.OrganizationServiceProxy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can post what value of connection string previously. Then we can compare it.

Comment: @TuanZaidi it works for version 8 but when I am changing for v9 then it gives that error.

Comment: What do you means by Version 8 and Version 9?

Comment: @user3934288 you are using .NET functionality so the CRM version is irrelevant. If `ConnectionStrings["CRM"]` returns a null (does it?) it means that there's no such connection string. You may be looking at the *wrong* config file or forgot to actually deploy it to production.

Comment: Are you *sure* the connection string is missing though? What is the *actual* exception message? What does the call stack show? The way the code is written you can't know whether `ConfigurationManager` returned a null or the `CrmServiceClient` threw. Post the *full* exception message returned by `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: BTW you didn't even mention *where* the error occurs. First line, second line? DId you try debugging? What are the values of each variable, property?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in 2nd line   this.crmService = this.crmSvc.OrganizationServiceProxy;  it gives null value.

Comment: @user3934288 put that in the question itself

Comment: @TuanZaidi versions of Dynamics CRM/365

Answer (score 1):

You can add a breakpoint and examine `this.crmSvc.LastCrmError` and `this.crmSvc.LastCrmException` these may give you some small clues about what is going wrong

If you are moving from CRM 8.0 to CRM 9.0, make sure you have done the following:

1. Updated the SDK files to the latest version (via Nuget or manual update)
2. Updated the version of .NET code to 4.6.2+
3. Force your connection to use Transport Layer Security v1.2 security policy

Here is how you force your code to use TLS 1.2:

```
public class get
{
    private CrmServiceClient crmSvc = null;
    private IOrganizationService crmService = null;

    public get()
    {
        // New line to force TLS 1.2
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        this.crmSvc = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM"].ConnectionString);
        this.crmService = this.crmSvc.OrganizationServiceProxy;
    }
}
```

Here's my [blog](https://jasonscript.wordpress.com/2018/01/10/connecting-to-dynamics-365-with-tls-1-2/) with these same steps and a little bit more documentation :)

Comment: None of which have anything to do with .NET's configuration system

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the error will occur with `crmSvc` so when you try to retrieve the `crmSvc.OrganizationService` will return a `NullReferenceException` as described in the original question

Comment: You *assume* that the error is in the second line, not the first, and that  `CVrmServiceClient` was created in a faulty state. The way the question is written suggests the opposite

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct: It is my assumption as with many of my answers. The OP said that the connection worked when connecting to CRM8 and only changing the ConnectionString properties for CRM9 did they get the error. So I would assume that the connectionstring property is being read correctly and therefore it is a problem further down the stack

Comment: Only Steps 1 and 2 are required.  It is not recommended by MS to not include the `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` line since this will force it to stay on 1.2.  So in the future if MS disallows 1.2, you'll have edit code.  Updating to .Net 4.6.2 should be enough, unless there is a configuration issue.  Also, VS sometimes will cache the setting when debugging, so you'll want to do a full clean before debugging after updating to 4.6.2